# Spring-boot Api not starting

Tags: spring-boot

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Configuration property name 'carWasher' is not valid:

```
Invalid characters: 'W'
Bean: carWasher-com.carWasher.properties.CarWasherProperties
Reason: Canonical names should be kebab-case ('-' separated), lowercase alpha-numeric characters and must start with a letter
```

Action:

Modify 'carWasher' so that it conforms to the canonical names requirements.

Comment: How do you write your ```carWasher``` class?

Comment: Update what you have tried  (code)and what is error log completely.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean in your application with the `prefix` attribute set to `carWasher`  It should be `car-washer`.